# Unpacking numpy array inside

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
a=[['Sb' array([4.24035696, 2.44817292, 7.41858935])]
 ['I' array([2.08076032, 3.69501392, 5.37518666])]
 ['I' array([6.35173963, 1.22916823, 8.9947238 ])]
 ['I' array([ 4.24036048, -0.04551256,  5.37518684])]
 ['I' array([4.24035383, 4.88618543, 8.99472472])]
 ['I' array([6.3999514 , 3.69501663, 5.37518685])]
 ['I' array([2.12897688, 1.22916548, 8.99472467])]]
```

I'd like to unpack the inner array to have:

```
a=[['Sb' 4.24035696 2.44817292 7.41858935]
 ...
 ['I' 2.12897688 1.22916548 8.99472467]]
```

I can't figure this one out in a simple way.

Comment: What have you tried? It isn't a simple structure; so don't expect a simple fix.  It's a (7,2) object dtype array.  `a[:,0]` is the characters column.  `a[:,1]` the arrays.  `np.stack(a[:,1])` will give you a (7,3) float array.  That could be concatenated with the character one, but getting the right dtype could be tricky.  String and floats don't coexist in one array easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment for explanation:

```
In [142]: array=np.array
     ...: a=np.array([['Sb', array([4.24035696, 2.44817292, 7.41858935])],
     ...:  ['I', array([2.08076032, 3.69501392, 5.37518666])],
     ...:  ['I', array([6.35173963, 1.22916823, 8.9947238 ])],
     ...:  ['I', array([ 4.24036048, -0.04551256,  5.37518684])],
     ...:  ['I', array([4.24035383, 4.88618543, 8.99472472])],
     ...:  ['I', array([6.3999514 , 3.69501663, 5.37518685])],
     ...:  ['I', array([2.12897688, 1.22916548, 8.99472467])]], dtype=object)

In [143]: a
Out[143]: 
array([['Sb', array([4.24035696, 2.44817292, 7.41858935])],
       ['I', array([2.08076032, 3.69501392, 5.37518666])],
       ['I', array([6.35173963, 1.22916823, 8.9947238 ])],
       ['I', array([ 4.24036048, -0.04551256,  5.37518684])],
       ['I', array([4.24035383, 4.88618543, 8.99472472])],
       ['I', array([6.3999514 , 3.69501663, 5.37518685])],
       ['I', array([2.12897688, 1.22916548, 8.99472467])]], dtype=object)

In [144]: a[:,0]
Out[144]: array(['Sb', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'], dtype=object)

In [145]: np.stack(a[:,1])
Out[145]: 
array([[ 4.24035696,  2.44817292,  7.41858935],
       [ 2.08076032,  3.69501392,  5.37518666],
       [ 6.35173963,  1.22916823,  8.9947238 ],
       [ 4.24036048, -0.04551256,  5.37518684],
       [ 4.24035383,  4.88618543,  8.99472472],
       [ 6.3999514 ,  3.69501663,  5.37518685],
       [ 2.12897688,  1.22916548,  8.99472467]])
```

Combine them into an object dtype array:

```
In [148]: res = np.concatenate((a[:,[0]],np.stack(a[:,1])),axis=1,dtype=object)

In [149]: res
Out[149]: 
array([['Sb', 4.24035696, 2.44817292, 7.41858935],
       ['I', 2.08076032, 3.69501392, 5.37518666],
       ['I', 6.35173963, 1.22916823, 8.9947238],
       ['I', 4.24036048, -0.04551256, 5.37518684],
       ['I', 4.24035383, 4.88618543, 8.99472472],
       ['I', 6.3999514, 3.69501663, 5.37518685],
       ['I', 2.12897688, 1.22916548, 8.99472467]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Yes not straightforward, I tried a few functions to combine the separate arrays but the np.stack(a[:,1]) was the important trick missing. Thank you very much.